# Wrong pagination for a filtered product collection

Tags: magento2.4.5

[image]

Hello

I used this event to exclude products with the same variation_group_id value from my product collection.
it is showing the correct items, but the wrong way.

Any idea how to correct the following:

- show correct items count (256 is the wrong items count for this filtered collection)
- show correct pagination (it shows 1-9 pages for 256. 30 items/page)
  but we only have 22 in our case.

```
public function execute(
            \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
        ) {
            $collection  = $observer->getEvent()
                ->getCollection();
            $variations = [];
            foreach ($collection as $_product) {
                $variationGroupId = $_product->getVariationGroupId();
                if (!empty($variationGroupId)) {
                    if (in_array($variationGroupId, $variations)) {
                        $collection->removeItemByKey($_product->getId());
                    }
                    $variations[] =  $variationGroupId;
                }
            }
            return $collection;
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the `$collection->getSelect()` curious how the query looks like and why it is returning duplicates... Also it looks like there is more to the story, custom logic that interferes...

Comment: it does not return duplicates sku. I have products that share the same variation_group_id attribute value and I want to show only 1 of these products

Comment: It's really hard to answer your question. This page is getting product data from Elastic search or not? It's very important. The correct way is to add the filter for Elastic request.

Comment: these are category pages, I don't think so, but I'll check and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should customize the collection in the same way that it was made - SQL.
Because in this case, you're removing the item of the array only.

I suppose `variation_group_id` it's a product attribute
**And in this case the possible solution might be next:**

All items will be grouped by some attribute that must be unique for all items in the collection

```php
$collection  = $observer->getEvent()
                ->getCollection();
$collection->groupByAttribute('variation_group_id');
```

Note
The attribute must be in the float table (listed in the catalog)
If it doesn't you need to join this attribute using this

```php
$collection->joinAttribute('variation_group_id', "catalog_product/variation_group_id", 'entity_id');
```

Example,
`\Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Product::addToCollection()`

Another important thing
I think you should use a plugin instead event

as an example, you can consider this one
`\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\AddStockStatusToCollection::beforeLoad();`

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey, 
I have added  $collection->groupByAttribute('variation_group_id'); to my code. 
Now, the page shows 1 product/page for a total of 9 items (9 pages).
our catalog without this custom filter shows 30 items/page. 
also, the groupby must ignore products where variation_group_id is not assigned (null)

Comment: @user33629 

Technically you need to group by NOT NULL and it might work like that


GROUP BY IFNULL('variation_group_id', 'entity_id')


$collection->getSelect()->group("IFNULL('e.variation_group_id', 'e.entity_id')");

BUT it can work if you're using a flat structure

Comment: Hi Sergey, 
Thanks for the update. The issue is still there with your suggested changes applied.

Answer (score 0):

Any update on this please? @Sergey Vlasov
I am facing the same issue

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208323)

Comment: we fixed the issue by overriding

<preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch7\SearchAdapter\Adapter" type="X\Y\SearchAdapter\Adapter"/> and modifying 
public function query(RequestInterface $request): QueryResponse